# Writing array as string (python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write entire array as text or csv file.

```
from array import array as pyarray
import csv

tmp1 = (x for x in range(10))
tmp2 = (x+10 for x in range(10))
arr1 = pyarray('l') 

with open ('fileoutput','wb') as fil1:
    for i in range(10):
        val = next(tmp1) - next(tmp2)
        arr1.append(val)

    arr1.tofile(fil1)
```

The problem with this code is it writes as binary file. I want to write as string, so that it would be readable. It is possible to create a loop and write file line by line, however real problem has millions of line  in `arr1`. What is optimized way to write in human readable form?

**Edit:**

After changing above code line to `with open ('fileoutput','w') as fil1:` i.e. `'wb'` to `'w'`, there is error: 
`write() argument must be str, not bytes`. So this is not solved the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: you opened the file in `wb` mode, so you would write in binary mode

Comment: `open ('fileoutput','wb')` -> `open ('fileoutput','w')`

Answer (score 0):

You opened the file in `wb` mode. This writes in binary. Write to the file in `w` mode to write it as a string.

```
with open ('fileoutput','w') as fil1:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try appending the results to a string then save it into a file, as following:

```
from array import array as pyarray
tmp1 = (x for x in range(10))
tmp2 = (x+10 for x in range(10))
arr1 = pyarray('l')
fileoutput_str = str(arr1)+'\n'
for i in range(10):
    val = next(tmp1) - next(tmp2)
    fileoutput_str += str(val)+'\n'
fileoutput_fn = 'fileoutput'
fileoutput_fo = open(fileoutput_fn, 'w')
fileoutput_fo.write(fileoutput_str)
fileoutput_fo.close()
```

You will have to remove the binary option `b` in order to write string into the file.